# Можно ли преобразовать .class в .java?

Tags: java, файлы

Всем привет. Наткнулся на файл file.class. Как я знаю, .class это скомпилированный файл Java. Так вот, можно ли преобразовать .class в .java - понятный человеку код? Если можно, то как?

Comment: декомпилятор юзай

Comment: условно можно, но это не будет исходный код в оригинале, поскольку скомпилированный код содержит не тоже самое, что исходный.  как это сделать - для этого написано довольно много программ, например, эта DJ Java Decompiler